# Deleting observations based on certain conditions in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause

I currently have the dataset below:

| Group | Start | End |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2021-01-01 | 2021-04-05 |
| A | 2021-01-01 | 2021-06-05 |
| A | 2021-03-01 | 2021-06-05 |
| B | 2021-06-13 | 2021-08-05 |
| B | 2021-06-13 | 2021-09-05 |
| B | 2021-07-01 | 2021-09-05 |
| C | 2021-10-07 | 2021-10-17 |
| C | 2021-10-07 | 2021-11-15 |
| C | 2021-11-12 | 2021-11-15 |

I want like the following final dataset: Essentially, I would like to remove all observations that don't equal the minimum start value and I want to do this by group.

| Group | Start | End |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2021-01-01 | 2021-04-05 |
| A | 2021-01-01 | 2021-06-05 |
| B | 2021-06-13 | 2021-08-05 |
| B | 2021-06-13 | 2021-09-05 |
| C | 2021-10-07 | 2021-10-17 |
| C | 2021-10-07 | 2021-11-15 |

I tried the following code but I cannot do a min statement in a where clause. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Delete from #df1
where start != min(start)
```

Comment: Please update the tags for the question with the RDBMS you are using (sql-server, mysql, mariadb, oracle, postgres, teradata, snowflake, azure, etc)

Comment: Hi, apologies for that. I have updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove all rows, that have not the same [start] you can join a subquery which find the earliest day, you can add additional `ON` clauses if you need to find other rows as well

> ```
> DELETE
>  o1
>  FROM observations o1 
>  INNER JOIN(SELECT MIN([Start]) minstart , [Group] FROM observations GROUP BY [Group] ) o2
>  ON o1.[Group] = o2.[Group] AND o1.[Start] <> o2.minstart
> ```

> ```
> SELECT *
>  FROM observations
> ```
>
> ```
> Group | Start      | End       
> :---- | :--------- | :---------
> A     | 2021-01-01 | 2021-04-05
> A     | 2021-01-01 | 2021-06-05
> B     | 2021-06-13 | 2021-08-05
> B     | 2021-06-13 | 2021-09-05
> C     | 2021-10-07 | 2021-10-17
> C     | 2021-10-07 | 2021-11-15
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=cf9c3ad825fb678b30596870ac44ce1f)*

Answer (score 0):

You can try this
`DELETE FROM table_name WHERE start IN (SELECT MIN(start) FROM table_name GROUP BY start)`

Comment: If you `group by start` while doing `min(start)` you will just end up with `SELECT start FROM table_name;` Furthermore, this subquery should be correlated (if it's supported in a DELETE statement on sql-server) otherwise only records that start with `min(start)` on the entire table will be preserved (instead of the `min(start)` for each `Group`).

Comment: this solution does not work for me for the reasons that @JNevill mentioned above.

Comment: Something like `DELETE tn FROM table_name WHERE start in (SELECT MIN(start) FROM table_name WHERE Group = tn.Group)` feels like it's in the ballpark. Not sure if correlated subqueries are allowed in sql-server and I'm making an educated guess at how to alias the table being deleted. I'm not a sql-server user.

Comment: @JNevill thanks for your response and help. This does not seem to be working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative using a CTE:

```
with keepers as (
   select [Group], min(Start) as mStart 
     from #df1 group by [Group]
)
delete src 
  from #df1 as src 
where not exists (select * from keepers 
     where keepers.[Group] = src.[Group] and keepers.mStart = src.Start) 
;
```

You should make an effort to avoid using reserved words as names, since that requires extra effort to write sql using those.

Comment: Really like this solution. Trying to understand it a bit more. From what I understand, we are creating a temp dataset (using CTE) where only min dates and their group are stored. We take this temp dataset and use a delete statement to delete observations from our original dataset that are not in the temp one we created. Is this correct?

Comment: Correct. Essentially a simple (not recursive) CTE is just syntactic sugar for a derived table (which is the approach used by nbk).